# Python Graph Analysis tool Graph_tool did'nt have the method that in the documentation

Tags: python, networking, graph-tool

I wanna perform the network analysis and visualization with a python library named graph_tool. I download and compile it from(https://graph-tool.skewed.de/), and there is no warnings and no errors. The version of the graph_tool is '2.2.44dev (commit 85f11ae8, Thu Jun 18 15:33:16 2015 +0200)'.

So I followed the documentation in the web(https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/quickstart.html). But There seems something wrong.
I found the "***Graph***" class didn't have the family method used to fast iteration over vertices and edges. And also I found the "**nested_blockmodel**" class and "***BlockState***" class did't have the *draw* method. I just followed the documentation. Even I read the source code in the web and compare it with which I downloaded. Those are different.

Could someone give me some suggestion?
Thank you!

Comment: @Tiago Peixoto Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.2.44dev is very old, from 2015. Get the current version, which is 2.22.

Comment: Could you provide the URL of the lastest version for me? Much obliged for your help.

Comment: @ Tiago Peixoto I also tried to download the grap_tool from the website (https://graph-tool.skewed.de/). But  the "nested_blockmodel" class and "BlockState" class still didn't have the draw method.  And the source code I download (https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) is different form the documentation.